# rxjava - SwitchMap - why is it not returning the most recent observable in a integer stream?

Tags: rx-java2

I have written simple code a test. i have created a stream of intergers and i apply a switch map.   [from the docs i found online in tutorials throughout](https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/map-flatmap-switchmap-concatmap/#switchmap):

> SwithMap() on the other hand is completely a different operator from
>   FlatMap and ConcatMap. SwitchMap always return the latest Observable
>   and emits the items from it.

```
 Observable.fromIterable(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))
 .switchMap { x-> Observable.just(x)}
 .subscribe{ Timber.d {"my result $it" }}
```

I was expecting the result only a single value . i dont know if switch Map is sequential like concatMap but i was expecting only a single value.

so i was expecting a result like this:

- my result 6

instead this is the result i got:

- my result 1 my result 2 my result 3 my result 4 my result 5 my result
  6

why did not not return just the most recent one and discard the other observables in the stream of integers ?  what is the purpose of switchMap then ?

UPDATE:  AFTER ADDING A DELAY TO THE switchMap it does the expected results. but im not clear why:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))
                .switchMap { x-> Observable.just(x).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);}
                .subscribe{ Timber.d {"my result $it" }}
```

now i get the expected results of :

- my result 6

can some help explain why i need a delay. i tried the following but it did not work without the delay:

```
 Observable.fromIterable(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))
            .switchMap { x-> Observable.just(x)}
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe{ Timber.d {"my result $it" }}
```

i think the [rule about switch map](https://www.journaldev.com/19300/rxjava-flatmap-switchmap-concatmap) should be:  SwitchMap would emit only the latest observable after a particular delay. It ignores all the previous ones.
It is useful when it comes to retrieving the latest data from a feed. It’s useful when you need to identify the latest among many feeds.

Can i get some confirmation this is correct ?

Comment: SwitchMap needs asynchrony to switch between sources. You specified a completely synchronous sequence so until each inner sequence doesn't give up the current thread, you get all sources. You can try with`just.subscribeOn` but there is no guarantee you get enough delays so that only the very last inner observable (6) has a chance to emit.

Comment: @akarnokd when would i use switchMap then ? if i have to add a delay to get it work whats the point. look at my updated post. im still on the same thread for everything yet simply adding a delay makes it work. if im understanding right switchMap should only be used when there is some slight delay between observables right ? so its good for cancelling requests to refresh a page or for search entries which have slight delay as user types. if its something without a delay i should not use it. is that correct ?

Comment: _**I'm still on the same thread for everything yet simply adding a delay makes it work**_ - No, In the first example, the `delay` operator changes the thread, and it's executing in the computation thread. Which means you are starting with the main thread and after the `delay` operator, downstream changes to `RxComputationThreadPool` and your subscription is happening in the computation thread

Comment: I can't know why you picked `switchMap` as you haven't specified any concrete original problem you wanted to solve. `switchMap` works best when its inner `Observable` goes asynchronous, thus freeing up the thread that feeds `switchMap` with newer items to map. You are probably looking fo the `debounce().switchMap()` combination that is very common for searchbox-type of operations.

Comment: this makes sense  akarnokd and @Sarath thanks also.